# Install R & RStudio to Local Drive not OneDrive

Tags: r, windows, onedrive

I have tried 4 times and every time I install R & RStudio, `Sys.getenv("HOME")` directs to my OneDrive.  I don't want anything I do with R to be connected to my OneDrive in any shape or form.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling R & RStudio, disabling OneDrive, and unlinking my OneDrive from my PC which now uses Windows 11. And `HOME` still goes to OneDrive.

I never had this problem on my previous machines since OneDrive was never automatically linked in previous Windows OS.

What am I missing?  Thank you.

Comment: Do you have any "special" backup directories like "Desktop", "Documents", etc. activated in OneDrive? [OneDrive Backup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vWUv.png) Sorry for german language in the picture but I hope its self explaning ;-)

Comment: Is it supposed to go to that page after sign-in to OneDrive?  It doesn't take me there.

Comment: Click on the OneDrive icon in your Task-Bar -> Top/Right on the gear -> Settings -> Manage Backup

Comment: Ah, yes. Desktop, Documents, and Pictures are all backed up.

Comment: Maybe RStudio takes the Documents folder as $HOME and therefore refferes to OneDrive?

Comment: Still trying to figure this out.

Comment: Still goes to OneDrive

Comment: @Cinji18 please see below for the answer - also not that OneDrive altering the Documents directories underlying path will affect PowerShell user profiles as well.

Comment: Can we please mark the answer as complete to knock this out? thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is simply due to the fact that OneDrive changes the default location of the underlying Windows "personal" directory (i.e. `%USERPROFILE%\Documents` to `%USERPROFILE%\OneDrive\Documents`) when using the backup feature.

---

In R for Windows the default *HOME* directory (not to be confused with the `R_HOME` directory, which is the installation directory) is found via the following progression:

1. If the environment variable for `R_USER` is set, it is used.
2. If the environment variable for `HOME` is set, its path is used.
3. Lastly, R will search the *SYSTEM* PATH for system-defined home directories, and on Windows this will default to the "personal" directory mentioned above.

---

Therefore, to answer your question all you have to do is set a user environment variable for either `R_USER` or `HOME` to your default `%USERPROFILE%` path.

You can accomplish this on Windows natively or use the system's `env\Renviron.site` file.

I would simply add a user environment variable for `R_HOME` pointing to your profile's path (i.e. `C:\Users\<username>`) either via *Control Panel > User Accounts > Change my Environment Variables* or just try searching for *environment* from the start menu.

To do via command line/powershell:

- CMD:

```
SETX "R_HOME" "%USERPROFILE%"
```

- Windows PowerShell:

```
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('R_HOME','%USERPROFILE%', [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User)
```

---

Reference:

- [R for Windows FAQ - HOME and Working Directory](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#What-are-HOME-and-working-directories_003f)
- [R Installation and Administration Manual](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html)

Comment: Should the CMD be SETX "R_USER" "%USERPROFILE%"?  I tried initially with R_HOME and it didn't work.    R_USER works.